# Caching Maven dependencies in Gitlab-CI between different stages and images

Tags: docker, maven, gitlab-ci

I have built the following CI in gitlab in order to execute unit-tests and integration tests.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF"
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/

unit-tests:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd source_code
    - mvn test -P test

intergration-tests:
  image: docker
  stage: test
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker exec -t account_service_container sh "integration_tests.sh"
    - docker-compose down --rmi all
```

The point is that when I use maven image between stages then I am able to cache maven dependencies in m2 repository. However in case of intergration test I use different image and the container with docker dind creates an isolated set of containers using docker-compose and then there is no acess to previously defined and cached mvn repository. Is there any solution to this case. Should I created customized image including all fetched and required mvn dependencies and keep it on docker hub and then use that image between each stage and in docker-compose.

Comment: Based on your yaml file, cache should work fine. How is your gitlab-runner configured ? Do you have a single runner or multi ?

Comment: I have a single runner, dind service creates set of containers using docker-compose are you sure that cache for .m2 repository is accessible for this ?

Comment: Cache is local to the runner. So if you're using same runner for both jobs cache should be available.

Comment: How about different services I mean unit test and service with dind which created isolated docker network with containers, then it is not common cache ?